# Reading flat file with combination of single- and multi-space delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I have a space-delimited file in which the spaces are variable and I would like to know the ideal method for reading such files. I have tried Pandas and tried setting up many delimiters but nothing has worked so far.

Data format that I am currently working with:

```
STBID DOCUMENTNO   DOCDATE    CUSTID    CT TOWNID           PRDID     PRD                                                BATCHNO    PRICE        QUANTITY     BONUS        DISCOUNT     AMOUNT       NETAMOUNT    REASON
642    752633       07-07-2021 0092      01 026              4419      OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S                                T-0987     1105.00      2            0            0.00         2210.00      2210.00      R
```

Data Format that I Need:

```
STBID,DOCUMENTNO,DOCDATE,CUSTID,CT,TOWNID,PRDID,PRD,BATCHNO,PRICE,QUANTITY,BONUS,DISCOUNT,AMOUNT,NETAMOUNT,REASON
642,752633,07-07-2021,0092,01,026,4419,OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S,T-0987,1105.00,2,0,0.00,2210.00,2210.00,R
```

Comment: How was the CSV file generated? While it's possible to clean it up, it would be a much better approach to generate a clean(er) file on the first place.

Comment: The CSV is being generated from another source and for now, just consider that we cannot change the generation method.

Comment: I provided [a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68918970/16343464). The only requirement is that the column headers are single words (without spaces)

Answer (score 0):

you can try below ..

```
df = pd.read_csv("texttest", header=None)
print(df)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0
0  STBID DOCUMENTNO   DOCDATE    CUSTID    CT TOWNID           PRDID     PRD                                                BATCHNO    PRICE        QUANTITY     BONUS        DISCOUNT     AMOUNT       NETAMOUNT    REASON
1      642    752633       07-07-2021 0092      01 026              4419      OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S                                T-0987     1105.00      2            0            0.00         2210.00      2210.00      R
```

Now use replace to convert spaces into comma..

```
df = df.replace(r'\s+', ',', regex=True)
print(df)
                                                                                                                   0
0  STBID,DOCUMENTNO,DOCDATE,CUSTID,CT,TOWNID,PRDID,PRD,BATCHNO,PRICE,QUANTITY,BONUS,DISCOUNT,AMOUNT,NETAMOUNT,REASON
1               642,752633,07-07-2021,0092,01,026,4419,OAD,X-MEN,TAB,.,20S,T-0987,1105.00,2,0,0.00,2210.00,2210.00,R
```

At last, save to a file without index and header.

```
df.to_csv('new_csv2',index=False,header=False)

$ cat new_csv1

"STBID,DOCUMENTNO,DOCDATE,CUSTID,CT,TOWNID,PRDID,PRD,BATCHNO,PRICE,QUANTITY,BONUS,DISCOUNT,AMOUNT,NETAMOUNT,REASON"
"642,752633,07-07-2021,0092,01,026,4419,OAD,X-MEN,TAB,.,20S,T-0987,1105.00,2,0,0.00,2210.00,2210.00,R"
```

### Edit:

As data is not consistent, so for single occurrence you can do as a workaround, but this is not Dynamic, better to clean data at the processing.

```
df = df.replace(r"X-MEN,TAB,.,20S", "OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S", regex=True)
print(df)
                                                                                                                   0
0  STBID,DOCUMENTNO,DOCDATE,CUSTID,CT,TOWNID,PRDID,PRD,BATCHNO,PRICE,QUANTITY,BONUS,DISCOUNT,AMOUNT,NETAMOUNT,REASON
1           642,752633,07-07-2021,0092,01,026,4419,OAD,OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S,T-0987,1105.00,2,0,0.00,2210.00,2210.00,R
```

Comment: This is not correct, it shouldn't split the "X-MEN,TAB,.,20S"

Comment: @mozway you are right but then, as you mentioned , it would be wise to know how OP pre-processing his data.

Comment: For single occurrence we can do `df.replace(r"X-MEN,TAB,.,20S", "OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S", regex=True)` which will produce the result but it not dynamic.

Comment: Not a realistic solution ;)

Comment: absolutely, that's i said workaround until he gets better approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution considering the data as fixed width file, using [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
import re
import numpy as np   # not strictly required

# read header
with open('multi_space.csv', 'r') as f:
    header = f.readline()

# get starting positions for each word in the header
starts = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\w+', header)]

# define colspecs (start,stop) for each column
cols = list(zip(starts, np.array(starts[1:]+[len(head)])-1))
## below alternative without numpy
# cols = list(zip(starts, [s-1 for s in starts[1:]+[len(head)]]))

# read fixed width
df = pd.read_fwf('multi_space.csv', colspecs=cols)
```

output:

```
   STBID  DOCUMENTNO    DOCDATE  CUSTID  CT  TOWNID  PRDID                  PRD BATCHNO   PRICE  QUANTITY  BONUS  DISCOUNT  AMOUNT  NETAMOUNT REASON
0    642      752633  07-07-202      92   0      26   4419  OAD X-MEN TAB . 20S  T-0987  1105.0         2      0       0.0  2210.0     2210.0      R
```

infos:

```
>>> df.infos()
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 16 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   STBID       1 non-null      int64  
 1   DOCUMENTNO  1 non-null      int64  
 2   DOCDATE     1 non-null      object 
 3   CUSTID      1 non-null      int64  
 4   CT          1 non-null      int64  
 5   TOWNID      1 non-null      int64  
 6   PRDID       1 non-null      int64  
 7   PRD         1 non-null      object 
 8   BATCHNO     1 non-null      object 
 9   PRICE       1 non-null      float64
 10  QUANTITY    1 non-null      int64  
 11  BONUS       1 non-null      int64  
 12  DISCOUNT    1 non-null      float64
 13  AMOUNT      1 non-null      float64
 14  NETAMOUNT   1 non-null      float64
 15  REASON      1 non-null      object
```